# Define new keywords in orgmode

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to define new keywords for org-mode in order to highlight text in buffer.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/a6mrdt/org_emphasis_characters_not_following_the_same/) and [this one](https://www.gonsie.com/blorg/org-highlight.html) which leads me to the following code :

```
(defface ex-face
  '((t (:foreground "red")))
  "Face for !")

(defface caret-face
  '((t (:foreground "orange")))
  "Face for ^")

(defface at-face
  '((t (:foreground "green")))
  "Face for %%")

(defvar my-org-custom-keywords
  '(("!!" . ex-face)
    ("^^" . caret-face)
    ("%%" . at-face)))

(defun my-org-add-custom-keywords ()
  "Add custom keywords."
  (loop for (delimiter . face) in my-org-custom-keywords
        do (add-to-list 'org-font-lock-extra-keywords
                        `(,(concat "\\(" (regexp-quote delimiter)
                                   "\\)\\([^\n\r\t]+\\)\\("
                                   (regexp-quote delimiter) "\\)")
                          (1 '(face ,face invisible t))
                          (2 ',face)
                          (3 '(face ,face invisible t))))))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook #'my-org-add-custom-keywords)
```

I restarted emacs.

Unfortunately, when I ask for the value of `org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook` I always get :
[image]

: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14)
:  of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian
: Spacemacs v.0.200.13

Comment: Why can't you set `org-font-lock-extra-keywords` the way you want  in your init file and be done with it? Why do you need a function to set things up and have the function called from a hook?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. I am actually too much of a newbie to clearly understand what you means. This code is put in the dotspacemacs/user-config ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to `(require 'cl-lib)` - that will define the `cl-loop` macro and you need to modify the code just a bit to use the `cl-loop` macro:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(defface ex-face
  '((t (:foreground "red")))
  "Face for !")

(defface caret-face
  '((t (:foreground "orange")))
  "Face for ^")

(defface at-face
  '((t (:foreground "green")))
  "Face for %%")

(defvar my-org-custom-keywords
  '(("!!" . ex-face)
    ("^^" . caret-face)
    ("%%" . at-face)))

(defun my-org-add-custom-keywords ()
  "Add custom keywords."
  (cl-loop for (delimiter . face) in my-org-custom-keywords
        do (add-to-list 'org-font-lock-extra-keywords
                        `(,(concat "\\(" (regexp-quote delimiter)
                                   "\\)\\([^\n\r\t]+\\)\\("
                                   (regexp-quote delimiter) "\\)")
                          (1 '(face ,face invisible t))
                          (2 ',face)
                          (3 '(face ,face invisible t))))))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook #'my-org-add-custom-keywords)
```

Assuming that this code is in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file (or some other init file), then restarting emacs and opening an Org mode file should allow you to enter something like `!!exclamation face!!` and get what you expect: invisible `!!` delimiters and a red-foreground `exclamation face`.

If you do `C-h v org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook RET` you should get:

```
org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is (my-org-add-custom-keywords)
...
```

If you do `C-h v org-font-lock-extra-keywords RET` you will see that its value is `nil`: that's OK. This variable is only to be used by functions that are called by the hook (BTW, my first comment to your question was wrong: I did not realize then the special character of this variable). The variable that *really* controls the fontification is `org-font-lock-keywords` and that is set from the temporary value of `org-font-lock-extra-keywords`. If you check that variable with `C-h v org-font-lock-keywords RET` then you should see your entries:

```
org-font-lock-keywords is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is shown below.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Not documented as a variable.

Value:
(("\\(%%\\)\\([^

    ]+\\)\\(%%\\)"
  (1
   '(face at-face . #1=(invisible t)))
  (2 'at-face)
  (3
   '(face at-face . #2=(invisible t))))
 ("\\(\\^\\^\\)\\([^

    ]+\\)\\(\\^\\^\\)"
  (1
   '(face caret-face . #1#))
  (2 'caret-face)
  (3
   '(face caret-face . #2#)))
 ("\\(!!\\)\\([^

    ]+\\)\\(!!\\)"
  (1
   '(face ex-face . #1#))
  (2 'ex-face)
  (3
   '(face ex-face . #2#)))
 (org-font-lock-hook)
 ...
```

Assuming that that is the case, the fontification should work.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works

Comment: If it has answered your question , please [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.